# How to add last hour of a day in a Date in Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a date like 10/14/2020 in my Date field. Now I want to fetch the date and add hours, minutes and seconds with this date which should be the last hour of that date like 10/14/2020 11:59:59 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truncate the date value back to midnight (just in case there is a non-midnight time component) and then add an interval of `23:59:59`:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC( your_date_value ) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
         AS last_second_of_day
FROM   your_table;
```

or add 1 day and subtract 1 second:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC( your_date_value ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
         AS last_second_of_day
FROM   your_table;
```

or add `86399` seconds:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC( your_date_value ) + INTERVAL '86399' SECOND
         AS last_second_of_day
FROM   your_table;
```

or

```sql
SELECT TRUNC( your_date_value ) + 86399 / 86400
         AS last_second_of_day
FROM   your_table;
```

*(But using intervals is more explicit as to their meaning whereas using magic numbers may not be clear when you look at the code in 6 months time.)*

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_date_value ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-10-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '12' HOUR FROM DUAL;
```

The queries all output:

> ```
> | LAST_SECOND_OF_DAY  |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-10-14 23:59:59 |
> | 2020-01-01 23:59:59 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=30c67864cfe569505be201d25293f560)*